# Using SassDoc to generate docs for sass variables?

Tags: css, node.js, npm, sass, gulp

I have tried [sassdoc](http://sassdoc.com), which I like, to generate docs for our sass mixins and functions.  I can't find any way to generate documentation for our sass variables, as in outputting html listing the variables and their corresponding hex/rgb colors.

Is this possible with sassdoc, or is there another similar node package to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving a [description](http://sassdoc.com/annotations/#description) and/or  [`@type` annotation](http://sassdoc.com/annotations/#type) should be enough.

**example.scss**

```
/// This is the color that should be used for coffee
/// @type Color
$coffee: #c0ffee;
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sassdoc = require('sassdoc');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('example.scss')
    .pipe(sassdoc());
});
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: How did you add the new section "variables"?

Comment: Just added the comments to the scss file. `sassdoc` does the rest.